# ¿Cómo guardar imágenes con Glide?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

Programo una galería en Android con la librería glide pero las imágenes solo se muestran, al dejar presionada la pantalla no me da la opción de guardar las imágenes, ¿cómo se soluciona?

Comment: si pones algo de código nos resultaría mucho mas fácil, ademas si estas trayendo las fotos de glide, las traes desde web y no las traes con propiedades, al mismo tiempo, glide no proporciona algo como para guardar las fotos, solo te da lo necesario para mostrarlas.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar un `SimpleTarget` mediante el cuál Glide te proporcionará un Bitmap y luego almacenarlo como si de cualquier otra imagen se tratase:

```
 Glide.load("http://somefakeurl.com/fakeImage.jpeg")
  .asBitmap()
  .fitCenter()
  .into(new SimpleTarget(250, 250) {

      @Override
      public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
            File file = new File("your/desired/file/path");
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
      }

  });
```

}

No he probado el código pero no ha de ser muy diferente a la versión final.

Más información en: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets